# How to block ssh from a certain area

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ssh, firewall

This might sound like a bit of a strange question, but I've just taken a sample of over 80 IPs  which have failed SSH authentication, and I've mapped them using an online mapping tool.

**All** of them came from China / Korea... my question is how can I block a range of IPs which would stop these countries being allowed to make SSH requests to my machine, as it's just filling up my logs and wasting traffic.

I'm using shorewall as my firewall if that helps.

Answer (score 7):

To solve this issue people usually implement tools like `sshguard` or `fail2ban`.

Find sshguard at: http://www.sshguard.net/
Find fail2ban at: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Fail2ban is SOOOOO easy and SOOOOO good

Comment: This. You don't want to ban SSH access from 'strange foreign places' you want to block SSH access from IPs that are trying to DoS or brute force your system.

Comment: Remember to add few machines you have access to the whitelist

Comment: Fail2ban even work for httpd and it look promising. +1 for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

Use geoip. [Xtables](http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/iptables-and-geoip-on-debian-squeeze) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution for bruteforce denials is denyhosts. Check it out at http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/

This will block any IP after a configured count of failed login attempts. It also works for FTP daemons and every other tool that comes with tcp wrapper support.